# Empathy starts offline

Tags: empathy, online-accounts

I have set Empathy to connect automatically to my online accounts. But every time I start Ubuntu the status is set to Offline and i get no messages. How do I make it to  go Online at startup.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo mv /filename /etc/init.d/
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/filename 
sudo update-rc.d filename defaults`

Script should now start on boot. Note that this method also works with both hard links and symbolic links (`ln`).

`/filename` should be an init style script

Comment: This doesn't make much sense can you provide a clearer answer then just filename since that is quite confusing